# Entity Framework doesn't save related entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have the following issue which drove me crazy during the last days. Now I found a workaround - but I like to search for the root cause.

I have an entity OrderItemAdjustment defined like this:

```
this.HasMany(oia => oia.Adjustments).WithRequired(a => a.OrderItemAttribute).HasForeignKey(a => a.OrderItemAttributeId);
```

No I'm trying to save a record:

```
var orderAttr = (from oa in _context.OrderAttributes where oa.Id = 4711 select oa).FirstOrDefault();    

var itemAttr = orderAttr.ItemAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ia => ia.OrderItemId == 4712);

var oia = new OrderItemAdjustment() 
{ 
   AdjustmentId = 1
}

itemAttr.Adjustments.Add(oia);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case the entity OrderItemAdjustment is not saved.
When I load the entity directly like this and replace line 3 it works:

```
var itemAttr = (from oia in _context.OrderItemAttributes where oia = 4712 select oia).FirstOrDefault();
```

Can somebody explain to me why EF behaves like that - especialy just not saving without giving any error?

Kind Regards
Jörg

Answer (score 1):

well, you should add your new object in your context before calling _context.savechanges(). so it looks like this

```
var oia = new OrderItemAdjustment()
{
   AdustementId = 1
}

_Context.add(oia)

_Context.SaveChanges().
```